# Real structure(s) of a Shimura curve ("complex conjugation" of abelian surfaces)

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, shimura-varieties

For a complete lattice $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ let $A_L$ denote the complex abelian algebraic surface that is isomorphic (as a complex manifold) to the complex torus ${\mathbb{C}^2}/{L}$ (this algebraic structure one might for example obtain by defining $A_L$ as the image under a holomorphic embedding of the complex torus into some complex projective space, thanks to Chow's theorem).

Let $\sigma$ denote complex conjugation.
Let $(A_L)^\sigma:=A_L \times_{\mathrm{spec}(\mathbb{C}),\sigma} \mathrm{spec}(\mathbb{C})$ (which in the projectively embedded situation should just be $\sigma(A_L) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$, i.e. the image of $A_L \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ under the obvious action of $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$).

**Question 1**: ***What is a lattice $\widetilde{L}$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that the complex torus ${\mathbb{C}^2}/ \widetilde{L}$ is isomorphic (as a complex manifold) to $(A_L)^\sigma$  ?  Is there an action of complex conjugation $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $\widetilde{L}=\sigma(L)$ (up to homothecy) ?***

The background of this question is the attempt to identify the so called "canonical" $\mathbb{R}$-structure on  a Shimura curve $X$ that is defined as a Riemann surface as the set of orbits on Ponicare upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$ by the Moebius-action of the reduced norm one elements of some maximal order $\mathcal{O} \subseteq B$ of some $\mathbb{Q}$ quaternion division algebra $B \subseteq M_2(\mathbb{R})$. Any point $\tau \in \mathcal{H}$ in such an orbit defines the same (up to isomorphism) abelian surface $A_L$ "with QM-structure" (I think I can refrain from defining it for the purpose of stating my question), where $L:= \mathcal{O}\cdot (\tau,1)^t$. The action of complex conjugation $\sigma$ on (the set of orbits of) $\mathcal{H}$ that ultimately gives the Galois-descent to the canonical $\mathbb{R}$-structur and should thus correspond to changing $A_L$ to $(A_L)^\sigma \simeq A_\widetilde{L}$. (At least this is what I infer the notion "canonical" or "natural" $\mathbb{R}$-structure to mean).

So this leads me to **Question 2:** ***Which (antiholomorphic) action of complex conjugation on the upper half plane $\sigma: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$  is such that starting from $L= \mathcal{O}\cdot (\tau,1)^t$, we have that  $ \mathcal{O} \cdot (\sigma(\tau),1)^t$ is homothetic to the lattice $\widetilde{L}$ mentioned before ?** (which by my intuition should be of the shape $\sigma(L)$ for some adequate action of $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$).*

If such an action indeed defines the "canonical" $\mathbb{R}$-structure on the Shimura curve as I assume, then I kind of know (see Proposition 1.1 from *"On the real points of an arithmetic quotient of a bounded symmetric domain"* by Shimura),that it is induced by some element $\epsilon \in \mathrm{Sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ in the normalizer of the subgroup of reduced norm one elements of $\mathcal{O}$ and which as order two modulo that subgroup. So the **second question really translastes to: which $\epsilon$ works ?**

I am aware that there is a possibility that $X$ has a unique $\mathbb{R}$-structure, but **I was not able to verify triviality (or non-triviality) of
$H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}), \mathrm{Aut}(X))$.**

**Edit:** After the discussion in the comments below, where a correct choice of $\epsilon$ has been derived, I realize that this choice is exactly what is refered to as "the natural $\mathbb{R}$-structure" in remark 43.7.1 of the book "*Quaternion algebras*" (by John Voight), where the connection to real structures of abelian surfaces is somewhat alluded to.*

Comment: Question 1: You can just take the complex conjugate lattice. So the $\sigma$ you want is coordinate-wise complex conjugation. Question 2: $\tau \mapsto -\overline{\tau}$.

Comment: @sdr: Could you please post an answer based on your two-line comment?

Comment: @sdr:  Is your remark based on a explicit formula for an embedding of the complex torus into projective space ?  Or how do you keep track that the most natural complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ corresponds to the most natural complex conjugation in $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$ under the embedding ?

Comment: @DGrimm: It's some very general thing. If you have $X$ a complex analytic manifold, there is another complex analytic space $X^{\sigma}$ whose topological space is the same but whose sheaf of holomorphic functions are the value-wise complex conjugates of functions on $X$. Kind of tautologically, your algebraic construction and my analytic construction are intertwined by analytification. But my construction is easily seen to produce the answer I said.

Comment: @sdr:  Ok, I think think I can follow this argument. Thank you. I am still a bit stuck with finding the correct invertible complex $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A\circ \mathcal{O} \circ \left(\begin{array}{c} \overline{\tau} \\ 1 \end{array} \right)   = \mathcal{O} \circ \left(\begin{array}{c} -\overline{\tau} \\ 1 \end{array} \right) $, in order to connect your answer to my first question with your answer to my second question.

Comment: If you take the lattice spanned by $1,\tau$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and take complex conjugates, you get the lattice spanned by $1,\overline{\tau}$, which is also the lattice spanned by $1$ and $-\overline{\tau} \in \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @sdr: No, but the lattice in question here is a lattice $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$, more precisely the lattice $L = \mathcal{O}\circ \left(\begin{array}{c}\overline{\tau}\\ 1 \end{array}\right)$. Its rank is $4$.  (So, abelian surfaces, not elliptic curves).

Comment: ...but allowing for some homothetic complex scaling of the lattice, any matrix $\epsilon \in \mathcal{O}^\times$ of determinant $-1$ should do the trick, i.e. for $\epsilon=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)$, take $\tau \mapsto \dfrac{a \overline{\tau}+ b}{c \overline{\tau} + d}$ as the complex conjugation ( at least on the Shimura curve, not necessarily on $\mathcal{H}$ itself).    Thanks, I think I got it now.